# Creating ConverationPost in discussion using rally-node

Tags: node.js, rally

How do I go about creating a ConverationPost in an existing user story?

I can't seem to get the syntax right:

```
const create = {
  type: 'ConversationPost',
  data: {
    Text: 'api test comment',
    Artifact: '/hierarchicalrequirement/287838839156'
  }
};
restApi.create(create)
.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
})
```

The error is always:

````
{ Error: /ConversationPost/create: 401! body=undefined
    at generateError (/Users/ts/Sites/node/tests/node_modules/rally/dist/request.js:38:11)
    at Request._callback (/Users/ts/Sites/node/tests/node_modules/rally/dist/request.js:114:20)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/ts/Sites/node/tests/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/ts/Sites/node/tests/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (/Users/ts/Sites/node/tests/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30) errors: [ '/ConversationPost/create: 401! body=undefined' ] }```
````

When I looked at dev tools whilst manually creating a post using the Rally GUI, I see this in my request body:

```
{
  "ConversationPost": {
    "Text": "testing",
    "Artifact": "/hierarchicalrequirement/287838839156"
  }
}
```

Anyone know how to go about this?

EDIT:

Setting `request` debug to true shows this in the request, which looks correct:

```
  json: 
   { ConversationPost: 
      { Text: 'api test comment',
        Artifact: '/hierarchicalrequirement/287838839156' } },
  gzip: true,
  url: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/ConversationPost/create',
  qs: {},
  callback: [Function],
  method: 'POST' }
```

I should add the 401 seems odd, since I'm able to query against this user story.

I also noticed the request from the rally node module is a POST request, yet in my browser the GUI does a PUT request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was correct. Annoying small print is that the "ALM WSAPI Read-only" makes Rally ignore the second setting, when configuring your API key in rally.

401 error corresponds with "access denied", aka something wrong with key or key permissions.